# PG::UnableToSend: no connection to the server in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg

I have a production server running `ubuntu 14.04`, `Rails 4.2.0`, `postgresql 9.6.1` with gem `pg 0.21.0/0.20.0`. In last few days, there is constantly error with accessing to a table `customer_input_datax_records` in `psql server`.

```
D, [2017-07-20T18:08:39.166897 #1244] DEBUG -- :   CustomerInputDatax::Record Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "customer_input_datax_records".* FROM "customer_input_datax_records" WHERE ("customer_input_datax_records"."status" != $1)  [["status", "email_sent"]]
E, [2017-07-20T18:08:39.166990 #1244] ERROR -- : PG::UnableToSend: no connection to the server
: SELECT "customer_input_datax_records".* FROM "customer_input_datax_records" WHERE ("customer_input_datax_records"."status" != $1)
```

The code which call to access the db server is with `Rufus scheduler 3.4.2` loop:

```
s = Rufus::Scheduler.singleton
s.every '2m' do

    new_signups = CustomerInputDatax::Record.where.not(:status => 'email_sent').all

.......
end
```

After restart the server, usually there is with first request (or a few). But after some time (ex, 1 or 2 hours), the issue starts to show up. But the app seems running fine (accessing records with read/write & creating new). There are some online posts about the error. However the problem seems not the one I am having. Before I re-install the psql server, I would like to get some ideas about what causes the `no connection`.

UPDATE: `database.yml`

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: wb_production
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: xxxxxxx
```

Comment: Are you having this issue in development or production?
Are your local connections to the db trusted?

Comment: Could you add to your question the `database.yml` for your environment? Are you sure that your pg_hba.conf is [correctly set up](https://github.com/mberlanda/wedwip#how-to-setup-your-postgresql-db)?

Comment: It is a on production server. The server has been running for over a year and the problem is recent. There is no change on the config/setup.

Comment: The app is deployed on an AWS service?

Comment: Could it be related to some gems you are using? I saw some issues on [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/628], `parallel` ...

Comment: It is on Ali cloud. The error is specifically caused by a line of code. Just updated the post.   `new_signups = CustomerInputDatax::Record.where.not(:status => 'email_sent').all`

Comment: Actually I don't know Ali cloud. Did you try to use another scheduler like `gem whenever` and/or to run this command invoking a rake task instead of calling directly the activerecord model?

Comment: Downgraded `rufus_scheduler` from 3.4.2 to 3.3.4 and the system starts to access the table fine. It seems to be related to the newer version of rufus_scheduler. Will check out `whenever`. thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the error is "RAILS: PG::UnableToSend: no connection to the server".

That reminds me of [Connection pool issue with ActiveRecord objects in rufus-scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248808/connection-pool-issue-with-activerecord-objects-in-rufus-scheduler)

You could do

```
s = Rufus::Scheduler.singleton
s.every '2m' do

  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
    new_signups = CustomerInputDatax::Record
      .where.not(status: 'email_sent')
      .all
    # ...
  end
end
```

**digging**

It would be great to know more about the problem.

I'd suggest trying this code:

```
s = Rufus::Scheduler.singleton

def s.on_error(job, error)

  Rails.logger.error(
    "err#{error.object_id} rufus-scheduler intercepted #{error.inspect}" +
    " in job #{job.inspect}")
  error.backtrace.each_with_index do |line, i|
    Rails.logger.error(
      "err#{error.object_id} #{i}: #{line}")
  end
end

s.every '2m' do
  new_signups = CustomerInputDatax::Record.where.not(:status => 'email_sent').all
  # .......
end
```

As soon as the problem manifests itself, I'd look for the `on_error` full output in the Rails log.

This `on_error` comes from https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#rufusscheduleron_errorjob-error

Answer (score 1):

As we discuss in the comments, the problem seems related to your `rufus` version.
I would suggest you to check out `whenever gem` and to invoke a rake task instead of calling directly the activerecord model.

It could be a good idea, however, to open an issue with the traceback of your error in the `rufus-scheduler` repo on github (just to let then know...)